# Cannot find APIServiceRegistrationController metrics in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I created a cluster with kubeadm, the k8s version is 1.16.4. And I installed kube-prometheus.
But I can not find APIServiceRegistrationController metrics in prometheus.

```
APIServiceRegistrationController_adds 
APIServiceRegistrationController_depth 
APIServiceRegistrationController_queue_latency 
APIServiceRegistrationController_queue_latency_count 
APIServiceRegistrationController_queue_latency_sum 
APIServiceRegistrationController_retries
APIServiceRegistrationController_duration 
APIServiceRegistrationController_duration_count 
APIServiceRegistrationController_duration_sum
```

[prometheus-dashboard1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ByX.png)

[prometheus-dashboard2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bklJh.png)

Comment: You mean no data is there right?Are you doing any apiserviceregistration?

Comment: I cannot find the metrics, there is no metrics named APIServiceRegistrationController_adds

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of prometheus dashboard?

Comment: hi,thanks for your replay , I added two screenshot.@ArghyaSadhu

Comment: We need much more info in order to help you. Could you please tell us:
- are you successfully gathering metrics from the kubelet and kube-state-metrics?
- are labels correctly setup?
- anything else that we could use in order to investigate